# Keep original page number on autorefresh

Tags: javascript, excel, html

I am working on a spreadsheet which is also accessible through a browser via Excel Web Access. When the Excel spreadsheet is edited via the Excel application, I want the browser window to refresh and show the changes made.

It is currently refreshing from the script below but there is an issue. If the browser window is set to page 9 of the spreadsheet for example, and the Excel spreadsheet is modified to make a change to page 14, when the browser refreshes Excel Web Access it changes the page to 14. I want it to stay on page 9, but if I click on to page 14 I can see the changes. Does this make sense? Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var reloadTimer = null;
var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);

function setReloadTime(secs)
{ if (arguments.length == 1)
   { if (reloadTimer) clearTimeout(reloadTimer);
       reloadTimer = setTimeout("setReloadTime()", Math.ceil(parseFloat(secs)*1000));
   }
   else
   { reloadTimer = null;
     location.reload(true);
     window.location.replace( sURL );
   }
}

setReloadTime(300);
</script>
```